# css sprite looks different then background image

Tags: css

I have 2 ways of calling an image

```
<table width="100%" height="81" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" background="thefolder/userbg.gif"> by using the background element in css
```

or this way by calling an sprite and using css class

```
.userbg{
    background-position: -460px -2px ;
    width: 180px;
    height: 81px;
}
```

and something like this

```
<table width="100%" height="81" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" class="userbg">
```

however it seems when i use the background tag it has an extra length and is strecthed out an bit in comparsion to the css class, any reason as to why this would happen? I checked the dimensions and they were both the same

Comment: it might be because you are setting the width but i am not sure

Comment: Any chance you could post a link, such as a jsFiddle?

Comment: hello I posted the images to show the difference http://i40.tinypic.com/1r3mn6.png  (the one with the CSS CLASS

Comment: this one with the background tag http://i39.tinypic.com/dy5344.png

Answer (score 0):

(This should be a comment, but it's longer, so I posted it as an answer.)

Several problems:

- `background="thefolder/userbg.gif"` is not CSS, but HTML.
- You don't "have to" use a CSS sprite. Why not just a "normal" background image, as you use the the first example?
- In your sprite example you have contradicting properties. In the CSS you write `width: 180px;` but in the HTML you have `width="100%"`. You can't have both - unless the 100% width happens to result in a width of 180 pixels, but it's still a bad idea.
- Unlike other elements `width` and `height` on tables are only considered suggestions. There is a good chance, that the browser changes the size, in order the content of the table fit.
- The images don't really help. The difference could be because you cropped them differently.